# Is ASP.NET MVC 2.0 released yet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Does anyone know if this has been released yet?

I went to asp.net and the Windows PI installs MVC 2 and it doesn't mention anything about RC's but then Scott Guthrie doesn't mention anything on his blog either.

Comment: The build date of the latest is of yesterday so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 2.0 RTM  was released on 2010-03-10, according to [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)

You can get other details at the [official Microsoft ASP.NET MVC download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9).

Comment: Excellent!!!  It's about time too. :)

Comment: And to answer the next question, "How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Application to ASP.NET MVC 2", look here http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes/

Answer (score 2):

[ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9)